# Когда пишу if (Serial.read() == 'qwerty') arduino не правильно понимает

Tags: c++, if, arduino

```
//Первая arduino, отправляющая значение

#include <Wire.h>

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(2);                // подключаем шину I2C с адресом #2
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent); // зарегистрированное событие, которое будет возникать в ответ на вопрос
}

void loop()
{
;  delay(100);
}

// Эта пользовательская функция будет выполняться всякий раз,
// Она зарегистрирована как событие (см. блок setup).
void requestEvent()
{
  Wire.write("qwerty"); // отвечаем сообщением из 6 байтов, как ведущая плата того и ждет
}
```

Тут вроде все норм, а снизу неочень

```
//Вторая, которая по задумке должна зажигать светодиод

#include <Wire.h>

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();         
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{

  Wire.requestFrom(2, 6);    
  while(Wire.available())    
  {
   char c = Wire.read(); 
   Serial.print(c);          
  }
  if (Serial.read() == 'qwerty'){
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);     
  }
   delay(500);
}
```

Но тут не задачка, if попросту не понимает условия т.е.

```
if (Serial.read() == 'qwerty')
```

Comment: Не знаю, как он там сравнивает... но что, в ардуине строки пишут в одинарных кавычках?...

Comment: Разве нет? Если в двойные то дает ошибку

Comment: А тут http://arduino.ru/Reference/Serial/Read написано, что read считывает один байт, а не строку ...

Comment: Так а зачем вы упортребили мультисимвольную константу `'qwerty'`? В первом куске кода у вас нормальный строковый литерал, а здесь вдруг - мультисисвольная константа. Почему?

Answer (score 2):

1. Одинарные кавычки означают "символ", то бишь, литерал типа char.
2. Двойные кавычки означают "строка", то бишь массив char в самом простом случае.

Из найденного в интернете

```
Serial.readString()
```

читает строку с Serial порта. То есть если эта функция работает, то итоговый код должен выглядеть так:

```
if(Serial.readString() == "qwerty")
{
    //Ваши действия
}
```

P.S. С ардуино давно не игрался, информация чисто из интернета и опыта.

Answer (score 2):

Это же C++, а не Python или Java.

```
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(57600);
}

void loop() {
   if (Serial.available() >= 6) {
      String str = Serial.readString();
      if (str == "qwerty")
         Serial.println("true");
      else
         Serial.println("false");
   }
}
```